# Constructing vector of POD using boost interprocess throws exception only in debug mode

Tags: c++, boost-interprocess

I am trying to construct a bip::vector of POD using boost interprocess managed shared memory. The following code compiles and runs in release mode, but crashes in debug mode.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// Forward declaration of Ringbuffer<65536>
template <uint32_t Bytes>
class Ringbuffer;

namespace shared {
namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;
using Segment = bipc::managed_shared_memory;
using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;

template <typename T>
using Alloc = bipc::allocator<T, Manager>;

template <typename T>
using Vector = boost::container::vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
}  // namespace shared

using MsgQueue = Ringbuffer<65536>;

using msg_queue_pool_t = shared::Vector<MsgQueue>;

template <uint32_t Bytes>
class Ringbuffer {
   public:
    struct MsgHeader {
        uint32_t size;
        uint32_t userdata;
    };

   private:
    struct Block {
        alignas(64) MsgHeader header;
    };

    static constexpr uint32_t BLK_CNT = Bytes / sizeof(Block);
    static_assert(BLK_CNT && !(BLK_CNT & (BLK_CNT - 1)), "BLK_CNT must be a power of 2");

    Block blk[BLK_CNT];

    alignas(64) uint64_t written_idx{0};
    alignas(64) uint64_t last_key_idx{0};
    alignas(64) uint64_t writing_idx{0};
    alignas(64) bool in_use{false};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto segment_ptr =
        std::make_unique<boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory>(boost::interprocess::create_only, "ShareMemory", 65536 * 20);

    msg_queue_pool_t* ringbuffer_pool =
        segment_ptr->construct<msg_queue_pool_t>("queue_pool")(5, segment_ptr->get_segment_manager());
    ringbuffer_pool->resize(10);

    std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error when running in debug mode:

```
boost_interprocess_issue: /home/rnd/.xmake/packages/b/boost/1.81.0/9a76068f70604ea18becd4a3064bdac1/include/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/rbtree_best_fit.hpp:698: T* boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<MutexFamily, VoidMutex, MemAlignment>::allocation_command(boost::container::allocation_type, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<MutexFamily, VoidMutex, MemAlignment>::size_type,boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<MutexFamily, VoidMutex, MemAlignment>::size_type&, T*&) [with T = Ringbuffer<65536>; MutexFamily = boost::interprocess::mutex_family; VoidPointer = boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void>; long unsigned int MemAlignment = 0; boost::container::allocation_type = unsigned int; boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<MutexFamily, VoidMutex, MemAlignment>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion `0 == ((std::size_t)ret % ::boost::container::dtl::alignment_of<T>::value)' failed.
```

The code runs fine in release mode. how could I fix the issue?

I had some extra finding, if I add a construction of single MsgQueue before the vector construction,

i.e.

```
MsgQueue* single_ringbuffer = segment_ptr->construct<MsgQueue>("msg_queue")();

    msg_queue_pool_t* ringbuffer_pool =
        segment_ptr->construct<msg_queue_pool_t>("queue_pool")(5, segment_ptr->get_segment_manager());
    ringbuffer_pool->resize(10);
```

the error is suddenly gone!

Comment: *The code runs fine in release mode* -- You can't be sure it is running fine in release mode.  Looking at that error message, the message is generated by an `assert()` call.  If so, note that `assert()` is a no-op in release mode.  Thus in release mode, you still may be running with the bug being totally ignored.

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: Some additional info, the code has been running in production for several months, without any noticeable misbehavior. However, I guess the memory misalignment(if I understand correctly according to the error message) has subtle performance implications that I did not notice.